# WPF Element Binding with ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In WPF I have the following structure:

`UserControl` > `Grid` > `TabControl` > `DataGrid` > `ContextMenu`

I would like to have the `DataContext` of my `ContextMenu` the same as the one for my `Grid`. This is how I am currently trying to do it:

```
<ContextMenu Name="contextMenu" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext}">
```

But I get the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=MainGrid'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext; DataItem=null; target element is 'ContextMenu' (Name='contextMenu'); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

I need to do it this way as the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` is different from the "MainGrid", and the `ContextMenu` is in the `DataGrid`.

Can anyone offer me some guidance as according to me this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that is not required. The DataContext set at the parent level is already available to the child. You can override, if you need. But in your case you want to use the same Datacontext.

Comment: Sorry that I did not mention this, the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` is different from the "MainGrid", and the `ContextMenu` is in the `DataGrid`.

Comment: <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MainGrid }},Path=DataContext}" - see if this works

Answer (score 0):

normally you would bind a property to your specific DataContext, and not the DataContext itself to another DataContext. But in your case, this should help:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=DataContext}"
```

Comment: I have in fact tried this before but the error remains the same!

Comment: ok, maybe you're right, but please note that the error you describe occurs due to the ElementName="MainGrid". In the upper Binding expression, no Elementname and no "MainGrid" is specified. So there's possibility you overlook that binding is to type "Grid". Just a hint(-;